# How to add git vcs_info to the prompt_bart_setup theme in zsh?

Tags: git, zsh, prompt

I'm trying to modify the [bart theme](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/zsh/zsh-34/zsh/Functions/Prompts/prompt_bart_setup) so it includes git status information. I got it to work, but it doesn't update when I change directories

I modified the bart theme by enabling vcs_info:

```
prompt_bart_setup () {
    # ...
    autoload -Uz vcs_info
    # Set vcs_info parameters.
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable bzr git hg svn
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' check-for-changes true
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' stagedstr '%F{green}●%f'
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' unstagedstr '%F{yellow}●%f'
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats ' - [%b%c%u]'
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' actionformats " - [%b%c%u|%F{cyan}%a%f]"
    zstyle ':vcs_info:(sv[nk]|bzr):*' branchformat '%b|%F{cyan}%r%f'
    zstyle ':vcs_info:git*+set-message:*' hooks git-status
    # ...
}

prompt_bart_precmd () {
    # ...
    vcs_info
    # ...
}
```

And populating the RPROMT variable (it also works with PS1, but I wanted to isolate the problem):

```
prompt_bart_ps1 () {
    # ...
    RPROMPT="${vcs_info_msg_0_}"
    # ...
}
```

This works if I create a new terminal session in a git repo, but it doesn't update when I change directories.

I've seen suggestions to use single quotes, but when I change it to this:

```
prompt_bart_ps1 () {
    # ...
    setopt promptsubst
    RPROMPT='${vcs_info_msg_0_}'
    # ...
}
```

The prompt shows literally `${vcs_info_msg_0_}`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with `promptsubst`. `RPROMPT="${vcs_info_msg_0_}"` will substitute the value of `vcs_info_msg_0_` when `RPROMPT` is first defined. That is the reason why it works when you open a shell in a repository but not when you change into one.

The single-quoted variant prevents this initial substitution and `setopt promptsubst` should then do the substitution everytime the prompt is used. But in your case it doesn't, obviously. Possibly, there is a `setopt nopromptsubst` somewhere in your zsh configuration that gets called after the one in `prompt_bart_setup`.

See with `setopt | grep promptsubst` if it is really set.

Comment: I checked, but it's not set

Comment: Once it is set, the single-quoted version should work as intended.

Comment: No, like I wrote in the question, when I use set promptsubst and `RPROMPT="${vcs_info_msg_0_}"` the right git prompt appears, but it doesn't update when I change directories

Comment: Yes, that is because the double-quoted variant is evaluated when the prompt is first defined. While the single-quoted variant is evaluated every time the prompt is printed, *if* `promptsubst` is enabled.

Comment: You can test it by running `RPROMPT='${vcs_info_msg_0_}' ; setopt promptsubst` in your shell. It should produce the expected results.